# Excel - Autofill columns based on input in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

In excel, when I enter "A" in "Input Column", I want, Harry, Josh, Rob and Peter to be auto filled as shown in the picture.

Similarly, when I enter "B" in Input Column", I want Kim, Nancy, Paul, George to be auto filled. Can anyone post the VBA code to do this or can I do it with formulas themselves?

Comment: you can do it with `VBA` or with `Formulas`. You just need to create some mapping that tells you what values correspond to which letters. For formulas, I would look at `Choose` & `Vlookup` or perhaps `Offset` and `Match` and `Index` to get you started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An automated code solution:

- Right click your sheet tab and select *View Code*
- Copy and paste in the code below
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to go back to Excel

This code makes the changes you require whenever one or more cells in `Column A` (ie your *"Target Columm"*) is changed

To use Column B instead try
`Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, Columns("B"))`
etc

**code**

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, Columns("A"))
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With
For Each rng2 In rng1
Select Case UCase$(rng2.Value)
Case "A"
rng2.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2) = Array("Harry", "Josh")
rng2.Offset(1, 1).Resize(1, 2) = Array("Rob", "Peter")
Case "B"
rng2.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2) = Array("Kim", "Nancy")
rng2.Offset(1, 1).Resize(1, 2) = Array("Paul", "George")
End Select
Next
With Application
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @brettdj That was superfast and works exactly like I wanted. Thank you and Merry Christmas!

Comment: @Regmi thx for the prompt close-out and best wishes for the festive season as well :)